# force the redownload of a nuget package

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

*This is my scenario:*

During the development of the nuget package A in project A in solution A we constantly need to test it in another project. For this reason we have a dev nuget feed that contains the unreleased package A. When building solution A it will be pushed automatically to that dev feed.

For testing we have a solution B with multiple projects that all reference package A from that dev nuget feed.

Whenever we rebuild solution A (and package a gets pushed to the feed) we want to use the new build of the package in all projects of solution B during testing.

Once package A will actually be released, it will be pushed to the release nuget feed and then solution B is supposed to pull the package from the release feed instead of the dev feed.

*And these are my two questions:*

What is the correct way to force a redownload of package A into the packages folder of solution B and make all projects use the new build of the package **even if the version of the package did not change**?

What is the proposed workflow for this (common?) scenario? Should I do it differently?

Answer (score 14):

```
Update-Package –reinstall <packageName>
```

This is automatically uninstall and install nuget package each time. Documentation is given at https://docs.nuget.org/consume/reinstalling-packages

Comment: As I mentioned above, I have to two feeds, the dev one with the temporary builds and the release feed. Once development is done, how can I make sure that it is pulling it from the release feed and not from the dev feed? Will the `-source` paramter suffice? Also do I need to do anything to all the projects in solution B? `Update-Package` als acts on the current project in the solution but not on all.

Comment: I hope you talking about the two sources for nuget. So you must have added both dev and release feed nuget source path. Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Sources. Add both sources. While installing you need to select the source from where you want to download the package

Comment: I have both sources active all the time. I don't see a way to select between the two active sources. I would have to temporarily deactivate the dev source. This doesn't look like a good workflow. I guess I will have to use the `-source` parameter.

Comment: if you working from visual studio then you have option to select the source in dropdown in nuget package manage console or using manage nuget select the source. If you using msbuild or from outside of visual studio then first you need to set source and then make restore NuGet.exe setapikey <ApiKey> -Source <Source>
NuGet.exe restore <SolutionFile>

Comment: For packages in development you could use pre releases tags on the NuGet package version. E.G. 1.0.0-PreRelease or 1.0.0-Dev

Comment: Plase note, in order to make this work you will have to first delete the local folder that contains the package, otherwise it will not overwrite it and it will keep the old version:
**Package 'Foo.1.1.5' already exists in folder 'C:\projects\bar\packages'**